# Python 3.5.2 : Checking characters in a string form a list not the same as checking using !=

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, join, lambda

I wanted to write a program that filters the letter "m" or "M" in a string.
While using this version :

```
sentence = "Therem are a lotm of Ms in here andm iM hope tmo find then amll"
not_good = ["m", "M"]
result = list(filter(lambda x : x not in not_good,sentence))
result1 = "".join(result)
print(result1)
```

Gave me what I wanted :`There are a lot of s in here and i hope to find then all`

When i tried this version of the code :

```
sentence = "Therem are a lotm of Ms in here andm iM hope tmo find then amll"

result = list(filter(lambda x : x != "m" or x != "M" ,sentence))

result1 = "".join(result)

print(result1)
```

It printed out sentence : 
`Therem are a lotm of Ms in here andm iM hope tmo find then amll`

Also if i wanted to make a string that contains ONLY the "m"s and "M"s using this code :

```
result = list(filter(lambda x : x == "m" or x == "M" ,sentence))
result1 = "".join(result)
print(result1)
```

It workded just fine; i got : `mmMmMmm`

Why didn't the second version of the code did its job while the first one did ?
Also, while `==` worked, why didn't `!=` ?

Maybe I can't use =! to search through a string ? Don't think so ...

Please help a beginner programmer!

Also english is not my first language, so I am sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: You are confusing `or` and `and` here. Your boolean test will *always* be true, because a given letter would have to be unequal to *both* letters, not either.

Comment: `x != "m"` will allow `M` character and `x != "M"` will allow `m` character respectively

Comment: Ohh, so basically they cancel each other out !

Comment: exactly, just keep in mind that `$a or $b is TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanted was the inversion of the condition `x == "m" or x == "M"`, and you could instead do `not (x == "m" or x == "M")` for that case.

As to why `x != "m" or x != "M"` does not work the way you want, you can see that if x is `m`, x is obviously not `M`, so the condition is True and thus the character will pass through the filter and end up in your result.

A more formal way to express this is via [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws#Substitution_form), but in short, for this case:

`not (x == "m" or x == "M")` -> `(x == "m" and x == "M")`

Also for the original, incorrect case that we had; while not what we want, the following expressions are identical.

`(x != "m" or x != "M")` -> `not (x != "m" and x != "M")`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `and` rather than `or` in:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x : x != "m" and x != "M" ,sentence))
```

The condition that `x != "m" or x != "M"` is always True for any character.

Comment: this doesn't really address the issue of *why* this is happening (remember OP is a begginer), maybe you should add that.

Comment: just explain the `OR` operator process and it would be fine

Comment: Thanks for answer !  I feel dumm XD